# How can I use loops in Karate to Create xml Request Body?

Tags: loops, karate

I have a request body as follows.

```
<PaxDetails>
    <PaxDetail gender="Male" name="Mark">
    <PaxDetail gender="Female" name="Alice">
    <PaxDetail gender="Male" name="John">
    -----
    -----
</PaxDetails>
```

Here PaxDetail is repetitive.
Is there a way in karate to generate this request body using a loop?

Comment: please search for other answers also: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bkarate%5D+xml+loop